# Installing Rabbitmq using helm3 from bitnami throws chart.metadata is required

Tags: rabbitmq, terraform, devops, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am trying to install rabbitmq:8.6.1 from bitnami chart repository using **terraform:0.12.18**.

My **helm version  is 3.4.2**

while installing I am getting following error

**Error: validation: chart.metadata is required**

My terraform file is as below

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "rabbitmq_load_definition" {
  metadata {
    name = "rabbitmq-load-definition"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.kylas_sales.metadata[0].name
  }
  type = "Opaque"
  data = {
    "load_definition.json" = jsonencode({
      "users": [
        {
          name: "sales",
          tags: "administrator",
          password: var.rabbitmq_password
        }
      ],
      "vhosts": [
        {
          name: "/"
        }
      ],
      "permissions": [
        {
          user: "sales",
          vhost: "/",
          configure: ".*",
          write: ".*",
          read: ".*"
        }
      ],
      "exchanges": [
        {
          name: "ex.iam",
          vhost: "/",
          type: "topic",
          durable: true,
          auto_delete: false,
          internal: false,
          arguments: {}
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "rabbitmq" {
  chart = "rabbitmq"
  name = "rabbitmq"
  version = "8.6.1"
  timeout = 600
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  namespace = "sales"

  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_secret.rabbitmq_load_definition
  ]
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use the rabbitmq operator https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/operator-overview.html

Comment: Hi, are you able to install the chart with helm? Looks like something may be misconfigured in the Helm terraform plugin.

Answer (score 1):

After looking issue([509](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/509)) at terraform-provider-helm,

If your module/subdirectory name is same as your chart name (In my case directory name is **rabbitmq** and my helm_resource name is also same **rabbitmq**), so I am getting this error, still not able to identify why,  With [reference](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/509#issuecomment-638826483) to,

**Solution**: I change my directory name from rabbitmq to **rabbitmq-resource** and this error is gone.